# angular 2 how to use fullcalendar

Tags: jquery, angular, fullcalendar

im using fullcalendar in angular2 ,Onclick of slot, the call is going to callback function in CalendarOptions.  select: callback function is calling but when i try to call angular2 function from inside select: there to make service (**this.calenserService.save()**) calls it throwing error :***Cannot save property 'save' of undefined*** 
Basically im not able to use angular2 component objects/methods inside callback functions like **select:** & **eventClick:**

**calender.html**

```
<angular2-fullcalendar [options]="calendarOptions"></angular2-fullcalendar>
```

**calender.component.ts**

```
calendarOptions = {   
    header:
    {
        left: '',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,today, prev,next '
    }, 

    slotDuration:'00:20:00',     
    defaultDate: new Date(),
    editable: true,
    eventLimit: true, 
    selectable: true,
    selectHelper: true,
    select: function(start, end, allDay)
    {
        let event:Event=new Event();
        event.id='785';
        event.selectable=true;
        event.start=start;
        event.title="Test";
        event.end=end;
        **this.calenderService.save(event) // This is Angular2 component object not able to access from here**        
    },    
    eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
        alert('Event: ' + calEvent.title);
        this.callFun() //**This is Angular 2 component function Not able to access**
    },        
    events:this.events //this.events is Angular2 class object
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use arrow function to retain `this`

```
eventClick: (calEvent, jsEvent, view) => {
    alert('Event: ' + calEvent.title);
    this.callFun();
},

...
select: (start, end, allDay) => {
...
```

Arrow functions capture the `this` where the function is created rather than where it is invoked.

See also

- https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/%27this%27-in-TypeScript

Comment: hey thanx, how to add events to calendarOptions from service component. how to update events can u give me any reference for Angular2 .